# Spring 4.3.1 scheduled task run twice

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem while scheduling a task into an application scoped bean using spring 4.3.1. My code is something like this one:

```
@Component
@ApplicationScope
public class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {

   @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "60000")
   @Transactional
   public void method() {
     do something...
   }
}
```

The scheduled method is runned twice. I debugged application context creation and it seems that the bean is loaded only one time as expected. 
Do somebody has some suggestions?

I added a BeanPostProcessor and I noticed that spring framework instantiate 2 beans one named **MyClassImpl** and one named **scopedTarget.MyClassImpl** any idea on how to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: application(method) will run as many as times from the completion of last method run. as per the config 1min delay between next start. if you are expecting to run once in day you need "cron" . http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

Comment: I want that this method is run every minute but actually it's run 2 consecutive times with a 1-2 second delay every minute

Comment: @Transactional marks the proxy to be created, hence created proxy also get fired. may be you want to annotate the @ scheduled on outer method calling   method()

Comment: This doesn't seems to be the solution, I have removed the @Transactional annotation and the behaviour doesn't change

Comment: If it is executed twice, it is loaded twice. Show how this class is loaded (component-scan) do you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved creating a new class not implementing any interface (**@Component** annotated) containing the **@Scheduled** method.

Comment: Can you say that again?